# Python List / Variables

Tags: variables, python-3.5

I'm a newbie programmer using python and I need help badly.  I have a large FDF form that I need to populate and the entry field list is in a txt file which I read into a (my)list.

```
mylist = {'NAME', 'ADDRESS', 'PHONE', ....}
```

Is there a way to create variables to each of the element in my list and assign values to them.  Like I want to assign:

```
NAME = 'John Doe'
ADDRESS = '99 Elm Street'
PHONE = '555-364-1234'
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking what I think you are asking, perhaps what you want isn't a list, but a dictionary.

Here's more info:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

Comment: I think that's close as I can get.  Thank you!